# Parse a nested XML file once in Power Query

Tags: xml, microsoft-powerbi

I am struggling with the following problem: I have an XML file that contains several nests. There are several nested XML files. The goal is: To read in all XML files in Power BI, i.e. Power Query, and parse them once. Do you have a solution, how to do that?

[image: First pic]

[image: Second pic]

[image: Third pic]

Answer (score 0):

There's a technique described here that uses a function to expand all table-type columns. This might give you more columns than you are after, but you could then use the Choose Columns feature to cut the results down to what you need.

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/

I have the code in a gist here:

https://gist.github.com/Mike-Honey/f5f3f708310eb1de7f4a